# hello I am very confused what does cd-- do?

Tags: linux, cd-command

I typed cd -- into my linux terminal and it took me to a directory I don't recognize. Where does cd -- take you? Is it your root directory?

Comment: What's weird of the directory? What does `pwd` show? Please [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/738878/edit) the question instead of answering in a comment.

Comment: Do you really mean `cd--` as you wrote or should that be `cd --` with a space before the `--`?

Comment: @Peregrino69 `--` is no directory, it means the end of arguments. As it is currently written is a syntax error.

Comment: @terdon Exactly this question must be addressed.

Comment: @VlastimilBurián Yap - I'm trying to figure out what the OP did, what the "weird" directory is and why he "cannot leave". I try not to AssUMe :-)

Answer (score 6):

The default action of `cd` when not given arguments is to move to the directory given by the `$HOME` variable. This is [mandated by POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cd.html):

> If no directory operand is given and the HOME environment variable is empty or undefined, the default behavior is implementation-defined and no further steps shall be taken.

Now, the `--` is [also a POSIX feature](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html#tag_12_02) and is used by many tools to indicate the end of options. This is very useful to handle names starting with `-` for example. For instance, in this directory, I have a file named `-a`:

```
$ ls
-a
```

And if I try to `cat` it, I get:

```
$ cat -a
cat: invalid option -- 'a'
Try 'cat --help' for more information.
```

This is where the `--` comes in:

```
$ cat -- -a
These are the contents of file -a!
```

So, in your case, you just ran `cd` along with `--` to signify the end of arguments, which translates into running `cd` with no arguments. The result would be that you moved into your `$HOME` just like running `cd` alone, and if you were already in `$HOME`, then it would appear as though nothing had changed.
$ grep foo -a

---

I am assuming that you actually ran `cd --` and not `cd--` since the latter would have given a much clearer error:

```
$ cd--
bash: cd--: command not found
```

Unless you have your own script or function named `cd--` in which case we cannot know what happened, but you would.

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to change your directory using `cd /path/`

I found this discussion online that might help: https://askubuntu.com/questions/711390/what-does-cd-do-i-used-it-and-im-now-stuck-in-a-directory

Answer (score -3):

cd changes directories. If you want to exit the directory, you can type `cd ..` and hit enter.

If all you typed was `cd --`, then you probably didn't change directories at all.

I hope that helped.

Comment: `cd --` would move to the `$HOME` directory, same as `cd` alone.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Ah, you see, I tested that in my home directory. Sorry 'bout that.